# Show and Hide element if statement JQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, show-hide, equality

I am a professional new to JQuery and need assistance with showing and hiding an element.

Goal:

if the widget title = filter selection
then show widget
else hide

this is what I have:

```
if ($('widget-title',element) === ($('.uc-box-text'.title(),element){
    (i have no clue how to tell it to show just this widget with this title particular).show()
else
    (widget).hide()
```

when I try to test it nothing happens, I don't know how to tell it to that particular widget not just the title.

May you all help me with this?

the html is long but this is the code for the widget

```
<widget type="pivot" subtype="pivot" family="" widgetid="58e69a5730a1e50000001015" class="widget columnar" data-ng-class="{refreshing:widget.refreshing, hidden:layoutState.resizing ||  layoutCellState.resizing || layoutSubCellState.resizing,
 renderMode: dashboard.renderMode, 'has-breadcrumbs': widget.metadata.isDrilled()}" data-ng-controller="dashboard-layout.controllers.columnar.widget" columnar-widget="" data-ng-style="{height: widgetHeight}" dashboard-columnar-draggable="" data-ng-repeat="element in subcell.elements" style="position: relative; height: 121px;">

<widget-header style="width: 100%; background-color: rgb(84, 84, 84); border-left: 8px solid rgb(28, 145, 192);">
```

```
 <widget-title style="float: left; font-family: opensansregular; font-weight: normal; font-size: 16px; color: rgb(238, 238, 238); vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;" data-ng-hide="layoutState.minSizeReached" title="TEST" class="">TEST</widget-title> </div>
```

Comment: It would be a bit more helpful if you could post your html for the widget as well.

Comment: You could use `.toggle()` and avoid the if condition.

Comment: "*May you…recommend some good JQuery for beginners book?*" – no, because any recommendation would be out-of-date in a matter of months, weeks, or days. As for helping you traverse from the `<widget-title>` to the `<widget>`, you'd need to show they're related in the DOM, whether ancestor-descendant, or siblings.

Comment: Also *"May you... recommend.."* - remove this from your question otherwise you'll get close votes as this is off-top for SO (as per @DavidThomas comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't give you an exact answer without seeing your HTML, but this should get you started:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.widget').each(function() {
    var widgetTitle = $('h2',this).text();
    if (widgetTitle === 'Widget One') {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget">
  <h2>Widget One</h2>
  <p>This widget <strong>will not</strong> be shown</p>
</div>

<div class="widget">
  <h2>Widget Two</h2>
  <p>This widget <strong>will</strong> be shown</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you could do `toggle(widgetTitle === 'Widget One')` too!

Comment: Yep, that would also work, it would just be the inverse: `$(this).toggle(widgetTitle !== 'Widget One');`

Answer (score -1):

jQuery makes use of ID, class, etc. to select particular elements. It's a good idea to use either a class or an ID on elements you want to work with.

```
<widget id='my-widget'...
```

Then you can use

```
$("#my-widget").show();
```

Comment: Not my downvote but in many cases with a regular structure the use of either `id` or `class` is unnecessary (not always, but often).